# How to make a triple relationship in code first Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How can I make a triple relationship in EF?
What I'm planning to do is something like this:

```
Table Foo: (ID INT TEXT VARCHAR)
Table Coo: (ID INT TEXT VARCHAR)
Table Boo: (ID INT TEXT VARCHAR)
Table FooCooBoo: (FKFoo INT FKCoo INT FKBoo INT)
```

I expected that using the code below it could be achieved:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Boo> Boos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Coo> Coos { get; set; }
}

public class Boo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Coo> Coos { get; set; }
}

public class Coo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Boo> Boos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

But the output is that for every `Icollection` the EF creates a simple many to many table.
Is that possible? Create a triple relationship using EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be:

```
public class FooCooBoo
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Coo")]
    public int CooId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Boo")]
    public int BooId { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo { get; set; }
    public virtual Boo { get; set; }
    public virtual Coo { get; set; }
}
```

you then have to set up the navigation properties in some configuration classes.

Comment: I prefer the ForeignKey data annotation above the object property... but that's just what he wants

Comment: you have 2 Foo here.  Typo ?